# CBCentralManager delegate is not getting called when connecting peripheral from iOS bluetooth settings

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am working on one application which communicates with BLE hardware.
I am facing some strange issue here.

When peripheral gets disconnected and then again connected iOS calls `centralManager:didConnectPeripheral:` delegate method.

But in some cases application fails to connect with device automatically event if peripheral is around and my app is running. In that case if I go to settings and manually connect peripheral from iOS bluetooth settings peripheral gets connected but iOS does not call delegate method.

Comment: What sort if bluetooth peripheral are you connecting in settings?

Comment: @Paulw11 It's normal peripheral[To check heart beats.] which continuously advertises data.

Comment: Your delegate method will only be called when you initiate the connection on your central manager, not when the peripheral merely connects to the device